# Spark (1.5.2) & Cassandra (2.2.5) Java Connector exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, connector

I'm using spark 1.5.2 & cassandra 2.2.5. So based on the recommendation, I used cassandra connector 1.5.0. While running my application (save operation), it's throwing this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to get converter for field "getCompanyid" of type java.lang.String in SampleDBOperation$Employee mapped to column "companyid" of "test.employee"
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.MappedToGettableDataConverter$$anon$1$$anonfun$5.apply(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:157)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.MappedToGettableDataConverter$$anon$1$$anonfun$5.apply(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:150)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.MappedToGettableDataConverter$$anon$1.<init>(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.MappedToGettableDataConverter$.apply(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:20)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter.<init>(DefaultRowWriter.scala:17)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$1.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$1.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:29)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:269)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.RDDJavaFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDJavaFunctions.java:61)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions$WriterBuilder.saveToCassandra(RDDAndDStreamCommonJavaFunctions.java:443)
```

Not sure, what's going wrong. Please find my pom.xml details:

```
<project>
    <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampledboperation</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Simple Project for Connecting to Cassandra and doing operations</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spark Cassandra Connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Question: What is the declared type of column `companyid` in Cassandra ?

Comment: Please note that adding ASAP/urgent is a good way to get downvotes here - please don't do it `:-)`.

Comment: Table creation details: CREATE TABLE test.employee (companyid text, empid text, name text, address text, location text, salary float, hra float, tax float, PRIMARY KEY (companyid, empid)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (empid ASC);

Comment: To make it simple, I'm just trying on Spark & Cassandra. I can change the versions if needed. Im unable to understand what is the latest most stable connector (java), though I have gone through various sites including: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

There is no clear explanation on which combination to use (Spark version + cassandra version + Scala version + pom.xml file). I’m not finding any article on the latest connector. Stepwise guide will definitely help esp on versions to be used, how to compile (using maven) & run spark-submit.